# React + Webpack: can't redirect all my routes to index.html

Tags: reactjs, redirect, webpack, react-router

I'm building a React application without using `create-react-app`, but using `webpack` to build it and `webpack-dev-server` to serve it.

My directory structure is:

```
myApp
|
|---docs/
|   |
|   |---dist/
|   |   |
|   |   |---bundle.js
|   |---index.html
|---src/
|---package.json
|---package-lock.json
|---README.md
|---webpack.config.js
```

and my **webpack.config.js** is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/docs/dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: [/.css$|.scss$/],
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&name=../assets/images/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&name=../assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './docs',
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

The [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) about historyApiFallback says this configuration `historyApiFallback: true` will redirect all 404 responses to `index.html`.

It happens that I am using `react-router-dom` and I have the following routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/article/:id/show" component={Article} />
        <Route path="/donate" component={Donate} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Everything is fine with `/`, `/about` and `/donate`, but when I try the route `/article/<something>/show` I still get a 404 error message, as the image below shows.

[image]

It says it can't find the `bundle.js`file. But then, it is not redirecting my route to `index.html` in the first place. If it were doing so, it would find the `bundle.js`file, as it does in the other routes.

How may I do this work?

**EDIT**

Setting `publicPath` to `/`, as suggested, won't solve the problem. First of all, `/` is not my asset's path.

Setting it `/docs/dist`, my real public asset's path, work to some extent. But the solution comes only if you use an absolute path when loading the resources.

Comment: Add `publicPath='/'` in webpack config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `publicPath` in the `output` object like so:

```
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/docs/dist',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
```

You can read the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) for more insight.

Comment: Why? My `/` is not public at all. It must not be served. Besides, I did it and the error continues. Would you mind to elaborate on this? I love solutions, but love understanding them even more.